# large numbers with printf

Tags: c, variables, printf

I have to write a C program which computes some values. Actually there should be no problem and my program works for small numbers, but when I try to print large numbers like 2^32 for example it doesn't work. Ok I know that an integer varable is 2^32 bits large, but can't I use a long variable or an unsigned long variable?

Why does

```
unsigned long erg = pow(2,32);
printf(%u, erg);
```

not work?

Comment: It doesn't even compile, to begin with.

Comment: You might like to try `unsigned long long erg = pow(2, 32); printf("%llu\n", erg);`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This Dependance on your underlying architecture. If you have a 32-Bit machine you can't produce larger integers than 2^31 - 1. apart from that Even a 32-Bit machine can't handle 2^32 without overflowing for the Range goes from -2^31 to 2^31 - 1.

Answer (score 2):

The correct format for printing an unsigned long is `%lu`, not `%u`